# Array Definition Modelling in MongoAlchemy

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoalchemy

I try to model my MongoAlchemy class in Flask. Here is my model:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("adfafdasfafag24t24t"),
    "name" : "sth."
    "surname" : "sth."
    "address" : [
     {
      "city" : "Dublin"
      "country" : "Ireland" 
   }
  ]
}
```

Here is my documents.py class:

```
   class Language_School(db.Document):
        name = db.StringField()
        surname = db.StringField()
        address = db.???
```

How can I define this like array model (address) in Flask?

**Edit:** I have already tried to my models like before asking question. But I took error like "AttributeError
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'".

```
class Address(db.Document):
    city = db.StringField()
    country = db.StringField()

class Language_School(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    surname = db.StringField()
    address = db.DocumentField(Address)
```

Comment: Author here. If address is a list you want ListField(DocumentField(Address)). You're getting the "items" error because MA is trying to parse that as a document field, which should be a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the [`ListField`](http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/schema/fields.html#mongoalchemy.fields.ListField) from what I understand.

Though, I am not sure you actually need a list to store the address, why not use the special document type - [`DocumentField`](http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/schema/fields.html#mongoalchemy.fields.DocumentField), following the example [here](https://github.com/jeffjenkins/MongoAlchemy/blob/master/examples/examples.py#L42):

```
class Address(Document):
    street_address = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    state_province = StringField()
    country = StringField()

class User(Document):
    name_index = Index().ascending('name').unique()
    name = StringField()
    email = StringField()

    address = DocumentField(Address)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.name, self.email)
```

Comment: @mathema updated the answer with some more information. You can also put document fields into list fields if needed, sample [here](https://github.com/jeffjenkins/MongoAlchemy/blob/master/examples/advanced_modeling.py#L14). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this solution but I took error like "AttributeError
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ListField](http://www.mongoalchemy.org/api/schema/fields.html#mongoalchemy.fields.ListField) and access the city as the 1st item on the list and country as the 2nd item on the list.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("adfafdasfafag24t24t"),
    "name" : "sth."
    "surname" : "sth."
    "address" : ["Dublin", "Ireland"]
}

class Language_School(db.Document):
    name = db.StringField()
    surname = db.StringField()
    address = db.ListField(db.StringField())
```